# Is possible to implement TextField in system_alert_window Fluttter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, system-alert-window

I used [system_alert_window](https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window/example) this library for implement sytem alert window. I need a Textfield on this dialog.

1. How do we implement this ?
2. Or is there other way to bring textfield in System alert window ?

   ```
     SystemWindowHeader header = SystemWindowHeader(
         title: SystemWindowText(
             text: "Incoming Call", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
         padding: SystemWindowPadding.setSymmetricPadding(12, 12),
         subTitle: SystemWindowText(
             text: "9898989899",
             fontSize: 14,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD,
             textColor: Colors.black87),
         decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.grey[100]),
         button: SystemWindowButton(
             text: SystemWindowText(
                 text: "Spam", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
             tag: "spam_btn"),
         buttonPosition: ButtonPosition.TRAILING);
     SystemWindowBody body = SystemWindowBody(
       rows: [
         EachRow(
           columns: [
             EachColumn(
               text: SystemWindowText(
                   text: "Some body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black45),
             ),
           ],
           gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER,
         ),

       ],
       padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12, top: 12),
     );
     SystemWindowFooter footer = SystemWindowFooter(
         buttons: [
           SystemWindowButton(
             text: SystemWindowText(
                 text: "Simple button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.blue),
             tag: "simple_button",
             padding:
                 SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
             width: 0,
             height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
             decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(
                 startColor: Colors.white,
                 endColor: Colors.white,
                 borderWidth: 0,
                 borderRadius: 0.0),
           ),
           SystemWindowButton(
             text: SystemWindowText(
                 text: "Focus button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.white),
             tag: "focus_button",
             width: 0,
             padding:
                 SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
             height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
             decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(
                 startColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                 endColor: Colors.blue,
                 borderWidth: 0,
                 borderRadius: 30.0),
           )
         ],
         padding:
             SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12, top: 10),
         decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.white),
         buttonsPosition: ButtonPosition.CENTER);
     SystemAlertWindow.showSystemWindow(
         height: 230,
         header: header,
         body: body,
         footer: footer,
         margin: SystemWindowMargin(left: 8, right: 8, top: 200, bottom: 0),
         gravity: SystemWindowGravity.TOP,
         notificationTitle: "Incoming Call",
         notificationBody: "+1 646 980 4741",
         prefMode: prefMode,
         backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
         isDisableClicks: false);
     setState(() {
       _isShowingWindow = true;
     });
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing so.. but with alert dialog you can achieve this stuff like this

```
AlertDialog( 
        title: Text('TextField in Dialog'), 
        content: TextField( 
          onChanged: (value) { }, 
          controller: _textFieldController, 
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Text Field in Dialog"), 
        ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Altert dialog won't stay when the app getting closed

Comment: i think you have to implement the class of system_alert class offline and modify it.@ஆனந்த்

Comment: we can't do that bro

Comment: We can - download git repo of system_alert and put relevant class into a project repo then modify by as per your requirement @ஆனந்த்